# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Arqade breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  2         17
Users destroyed                                 117          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Users contacted                                   8          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           141      5,958
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                7        714
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         50      6,291
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                3      3,240
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 7      7,107
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               51      6,716
Tags merged                                     164          0
Tag synonyms proposed                           215          0
Tag synonyms created                            216          0
Revisions redacted                                6          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               32         22
Questions protected                              36        195
Questions migrated                                6          4
Questions merged                                  3          0
Questions flagged⁴                               26      2,487
Questions closed                                273      1,694
Question flags handled⁴                         352      2,161
Posts unlocked                                    5          6
Posts undeleted                                  27         90
Posts locked                                     18        395
Posts deleted⁵                                1,680      3,540
Posts bumped                                      0      7,558
Escalations to the CM team                        7          0
Comments undeleted                               40          0
Comments flagged                                  1      3,159
Comments deleted⁶                             2,846      2,673
Comment flags handled                         1,679      1,481
Answers flagged                                  97      7,422
Answer flags handled                          5,402      2,117
All comments on a post moved to chat             11          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Under what circumstances can Community lock or unlock posts?

Comment: Migrations, spam, etc. @Unionhawk