# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers?
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Arqade over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 7 | 33 |
| Users destroyed³ | 79 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 9 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 16 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 1 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 114 | 8,644 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 19 | 1,059 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 24 | 4,899 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 6 | 2,419 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 1 | 6,522 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 45 | 10,473 |
| Tags merged | 39 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 59 | 1 |
| Tag synonyms created | 60 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 7 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 2 | 4 |
| Questions reopened | 41 | 58 |
| Questions protected | 50 | 191 |
| Questions migrated | 9 | 3 |
| Questions merged | 9 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 47 | 3,045 |
| Questions closed | 297 | 2,360 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 535 | 2,558 |
| Posts unlocked | 8 | 10 |
| Posts undeleted | 36 | 100 |
| Posts locked | 17 | 336 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 1,707 | 3,721 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 2,178 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 7 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 45 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 8 | 3,146 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 3,034 | 3,588 |
| Comment flags handled | 912 | 2,242 |
| Answers flagged | 162 | 5,794 |
| Answer flags handled | 4,179 | 1,782 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 8 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13213/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Most of the values increased by about 25%. If that can be extrapolated to total site growth, that makes for some pretty impressive change for one year.

Comment: Because of the new decade is there any chance we can see a similar dataset from 2010, right after Arqade was opened?

Comment: Apparently I was involved in 18% of the close votes this year, wow. (Not exactly, some weren't closed that I voted on.) Also, I'm first place in points of 2019, woohoo! \o/

Comment: @PausePause: No new decade, that is next year. Year 1 was actually the first.

Comment: Next year begins the 203rd decade, but no one really references those @fabian... This year is the first of the '20s, which folks will likely be referencing for years to come.

Comment: @FabianRöling https://xkcd.com/2249/