# 2023: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It’s that time of the year again! As we wave goodbye to last year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here might be aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks — folks like you. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference in ensuring Stack Exchange sites remain a valuable source of high-quality content on the web.

So as we say goodbye to 2023 (and January 2024… ahem) and move into 2024, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmN7M.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Arqade over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community User¹ | Community² |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 469 | 220 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 68 | 127 | 471 |
| Bounties canceled | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Comment flags handled | 263 | 35 | 2 |
| Comments deleted⁸ | 777 | 17 | 424 |
| Comments flagged | 1 | 1 | 297 |
| Comments undeleted | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 1,191 | 0 |
| Posts deleted⁷ | 263 | 704 | 292 |
| Posts locked | 8 | 97 | 0 |
| Posts undeleted | 6 | 4 | 36 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Question flags handled⁶ | 124 | 295 | 2 |
| Questions closed | 265 | 242 | 3 |
| Questions flagged⁶ | 26 | 2 | 381 |
| Questions merged | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 0 | 23 | 3 |
| Questions reopened | 12 | 6 | 1 |
| Questions unprotected | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 71 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 70 | 0 | 1 |
| Tags merged | 58 | 0 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Close votes" queue | 246 | 0 | 1,560 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First answers" queue | 41 | 0 | 593 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First questions" queue | 35 | 0 | 836 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Late answers" queue | 11 | 0 | 386 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Low quality posts" queue | 92 | 0 | 579 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Reopen votes" queue | 14 | 0 | 88 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Suggested edits" queue | 176 | 90 | 726 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Triage" queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User banned from review | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Users destroyed⁴ | 134 | 0 | 0 |
| Users suspended³ | 4 | 60 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ This refers to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² This refers to [the membership of Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

³ The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

⁴ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁵ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁶ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). The community² can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁷ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁸ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2022: a year in moderation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16668/2022-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222023%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396299/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2024! ^_^

Comment: 777 comments deleted, calculated

Comment: @Unionhawk Well Mods have Read, Write AND Execute privileges, so it checks out :P

Comment: How and why does the Community User reopen questions, especially in such a high proportion on Arqade?

Comment: Related: [What are the conditions and events that trigger the Community User to reopen questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396358/162827)

Comment: Hey JNat, if you can, could you review the comments here, on [the one answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17002/163757) as well as the answer itself to answer some questions? Probably best to make answer of its own answering them.

Comment: Sorry, @TimmyJim — I posted these network-wide, so have a ton of comments and answers to respond to; will try to get to these this week or the next!

Answer (score 5):

I have some questions about these stats and I hope someone can shed some light on them:

| Action | Moderators | Community User | Community |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Questions closed | 265 | 242 | 3 |
| Questions reopened | 12 | 6 | 1 |
| Tasks reviewed: "Close votes" queue | 246 | 0 | 1,560 |
| Tasks reviewed: "Reopen votes" queue | 14 | 0 | 88 |

##### Questions reopened and closed by the Community User

According to the table, almost half of the questions that were closed (242/510 or 47%) and a third of the questions that were reopened (6/19 or 32%) were done by the Community User bot. I know that the Community User owns the close vote when an asker agrees with a pending duplicate close vote, as explained in this [Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/162827). Is this what happened here - did the askers of 47% of the closed questions agree that their questions were duplicates?

##### Possible discrepancies

[Schism](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31508/schism) also raised interesting points regarding some possible discrepancies in the [comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16999/2023-a-year-in-moderation#comment49764_17002):

> by my count, [there were 92 reopen reviews from community members](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history?skipped=false), and 9 from Timmy Jim, for a total of 101. Which ones are being excluded in the reported 88 tasks reviewed?

##### Questions closed by moderators

The table also shows that more than half of the questions that were closed (265/510 or 52%) were closed by moderators. This is much higher than the number of questions closed by the community (non-moderators), which is only 3/510 or 0.6%. Does this mean that we don’t have enough active users reviewing the close vote review queue, and that the moderators have to step in more often? The stats seem to contradict this, as they indicate that most of the close vote reviews are done by the community.

Comment: I often see that Timmy Jim casts the final close vote on a flagged post, so that definitely counts as "closed by moderator". But 3/510 is a really low stat.

Comment: [JNat confirmed on last years report](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16668/2022-a-year-in-moderation#comment49002_16668) that yes, if a moderator closes a post as the fifth vote (or as any vote since a moderators vote will automatically close a post), its considered a moderator action.

Comment: And I'll add - I will often wait until there are 3 to 4 votes already on a review item before I make my vote (unless its a blatantly off-topic post like a game ID post without an artifact), to give the community a chance at it first. It's one thing I wish could be a _little_ better since sometimes I just want to cast a normal close vote and not have it count as a moderator close vote.  After all, I am a community member too :) But I do think there are less people going through the review queues now a days

Comment: I typically close posts via the review queue, and looking at "My Reviews", I have to go back 7 pages to see my first 2023 review item I handled.  I think there are 50 items per page, so 6ish pages of 50 each where the majority of my votes were "close", I'd say the math adds up to the 265 seen in the table (that's just counting me too, not the other mods!)  For perspective, Robotnik has performed 5 close review items for 2023, with only 1 of them being a close vote! (Sorry to call you out Robotnik)

Comment: +1. I also have questions about the "Questions reopened" stat. [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/403064/revisions) [are](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/403615/revisions) [three](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/403634/revisions) questions reopened by, as far as I can tell, 5 community members. Where is the _1_ coming from?

Comment: Similarly, by my count, [there were 92 reopen reviews from community members](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history?skipped=false), and 9 from Timmy Jim, for a total of 101. Which ones are being excluded in the reported 88 tasks reviewed?

Comment: @Schism Hmm. Interesting. All three of those reopened questions should count as a Community reopened question. In two of those three reopened questions, the OP has cast a reopen vote. So maybe that counted as "Community User" reopened question (though it shouldn't).

Comment: @Schism The discrepancies regarding the "Questions reopened" stat have been explained in this Meta SE post: [What are the conditions and events that trigger the Community User to reopen questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396375/162827)

Comment: @TimmyJim - I likewise tend to hold off on close votes, not that there's ever much in the queues when I'm looking anyway - the queue is currently completely empty. I also have a tendency to err on good faith: a lot of the close votes I see - while coming from a good place - could potentially be solved by a third-party edit, imo. This was true before I was a mod as well.